# Another sound for a push notification

Tags: iphone, json

I am trying to send myself a remote notification with another sound than the default sound(tri-tone).
But when I add "sound" : "chime", I'm not getting another sound?

Can someone help me to put the Horn as notification sound?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its a big issue.You just need to download one wave file with the sound you like and add it in the the resource folder and code it accordingly.

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) 
    {
        self.deviceToken1 = @"your token key";
        self.payload = @"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"You got a new message!\",\"badge\":5,\"sound\":\"beep.wav\"},\"acme1\":\"bar\",\"acme2\":42}";
        //  self.payload = @"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"This is some fany message.\",\"badge\":1}}";
        self.certificate = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"certi_identity(2)" ofType:@"cer"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: But I want to use the standard sound from apple. Not just the tri-tone. or some other custom sound

Comment: u mean default APPLE tone? I went through so many wikis at the time i implemented APNS,so as per my knowledge,you need to add some wave file.

Comment: you can refer to this site:http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/apns-client-development-certificate.html

Comment: So...unlike the examples apple use. I can't use something like sound : chime without adding a sound -.-"

Comment: I think so.You will get some sounds on net easily.